# How to cleanup on suspense (ctrl-z) in a Bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, signals, job-control, trap

I have the following script:

```bash
suspense_cleanup () {
  echo "Suspense clean up..."
}

int_cleanup () {
  echo "Int clean up..."
  exit 0
}

trap 'suspense_cleanup' SIGTSTP 
trap 'int_cleanup' SIGINT

sleep 600
```

If I run it and press `Ctrl-C`, `Int clean up...` show and it exits.

But if I press `Ctrl-Z`, the `^Z` characters are displayed on the screen and then it hangs.

How can I:

- Run some cleanup code on `Ctrl-Z`, maybe even echoing something, and
- proceed with the suspension afterwards?

Randomly reading through the glibc documentation, I found this:

> Applications that disable the normal interpretation of the SUSP
> character should provide some other mechanism for the user to stop the
> job. When the user invokes this mechanism, the program should send a
> SIGTSTP signal to the process group of the process, not just to the
> process itself.

But I'm not sure if that's applicable here, and in any case it doesn't seem to work.

**Context:** I'm trying to make an interactive shell script which supports all the suspense-related features that Vim/Neovim supports. Namely:

1. Ability to suspend programatically (with `:suspend`, instead of just letting the user press Ctrl-z)
2. Ability to perform an action before suspending (autosave in Vim)
3. Ability to perform an action before resuming (VimResume in NeoVim)

**Edit:** Changing `sleep 600` to `for x in {1..100}; do sleep 6; done` also doesn't work.

**Edit 2:** It works when replacing `sleep 600` with `sleep 600 & wait`. I'm not at all sure why or how that works, or what are the limitations of something like this.

Comment: See [Why did my trap not trigger?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282631/100397)

Comment: Change the `sleep 600` to something like `for x in {1..100}; do sleep 6; done` and try again. You _should_ see the trap fire within 6 seconds of you hitting Ctrl z

Comment: Thanks for your help roaima, but that change didn't work.

Comment: Looking further into this

Comment: Looks like it may be a bug :-( I've been running `strace` on the executable and it really doesn't recover well does it

Comment: Where do you think the bug might come from? I have the same issue with Zsh.

Comment: I'm not sure. I see the same behaviour in `dash` too. But only for SIGTSTP

Comment: Btw I found out that it works when replacing `sleep 600` with `sleep 600 & wait`. I'm not at all sure why or how that works, but I'll look a bit more into it.

Comment: From the answer linked to in the first comment: "the `trap` won't execute until the `sleep …` has completed". Ctrl+z sends SIGTSTP to the entire foreground process group. In your case `sleep` is in the process group, it gets stopped, it cannot complete when it's stopped. Send SIGCONT to the `sleep` process and wait long enough, then you will see your trap works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signals handling on Linux and other UNIX-like systems is a very
complex subject with many actors at play: kernel terminal driver,
parent -> child process relation, process groups, controlling
terminal, shell handling of signals with job control enabled/disabled, signal
handlers in individual processes and possibly more.

First, <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>,
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> keybindings are not handled by shell
but by the kernel. You can see the default definitions with `stty -a`:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 64; columns 212; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Here we see `intr = ^C` and `susp = ^Z`. stty in turn gets this
information from the kernel using TCGETS ioctl
[syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call):

```
$ strace stty -a |& grep TCGETS
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
```

The default keybindings are defined in Linux kernel code in

```
#define INIT_C_CC {         \
        [VINTR] = 'C'-0x40, \
        [VQUIT] = '\\'-0x40,        \
        [VERASE] = '\177',  \
        [VKILL] = 'U'-0x40, \
        [VEOF] = 'D'-0x40,  \
        [VSTART] = 'Q'-0x40,        \
        [VSTOP] = 'S'-0x40, \
        [VSUSP] = 'Z'-0x40, \
        [VREPRINT] = 'R'-0x40,      \
        [VDISCARD] = 'O'-0x40,      \
        [VWERASE] = 'W'-0x40,       \
        [VLNEXT] = 'V'-0x40,        \
        INIT_C_CC_VDSUSP_EXTRA      \
        [VMIN] = 1 }
```

The default actions are also defined:

```
static void n_tty_receive_char_special(struct tty_struct *tty, unsigned char c,
                                       bool lookahead_done)
{
        struct n_tty_data *ldata = tty->disc_data;

        if (I_IXON(tty) && n_tty_receive_char_flow_ctrl(tty, c, lookahead_done))
                return;

        if (L_ISIG(tty)) {
                if (c == INTR_CHAR(tty)) {
                        n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGINT, c);
                        return;
                } else if (c == QUIT_CHAR(tty)) {
                        n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGQUIT, c);
                        return;
                } else if (c == SUSP_CHAR(tty)) {
                        n_tty_receive_signal_char(tty, SIGTSTP, c);
                        return;
                }
```

The signal finally goes to __kill_pgrp_info() that says:

```
/*
 * __kill_pgrp_info() sends a signal to a process group: this is what the tty
 * control characters do (^C, ^Z etc)
 * - the caller must hold at least a readlock on tasklist_lock
 */
```

That's important for our story - the signal generated with
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> is
sent to foreground [*process
group*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group) created by parent
interactive shell whose leader is a newly run script. The script and
its [children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) belong to
one group.

Therefore, as correctly noted in the comments by user [Kamil
Maciorowski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108618/kamil-maciorowski),
when you send <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> after starting your
script SIGTSTP signal is received both by the script *and* `sleep`
because when a signal is sent to a group it received by all processes
in the group. It would be easy to see if you removed traps from your
code so that it looks like that (BTW, always add a
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/shebang_(unix), it's not defined what
should happen if there is no shebang))

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# suspense_cleanup () {
#   echo "Suspense clean up..."
# }

# int_cleanup () {
#   echo "Int clean up..."
#   exit 0
# }

# trap 'suspense_cleanup' SIGTSTP
# trap 'int_cleanup' SIGINT

sleep 600
```

Run it (I named it sigtstp.sh) and stop it:

```
$ ./sigtstp.sh
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./sigtstp.sh
$ ps aux | grep -e '[s]leep 600' -e '[s]igtstp.sh'
ja       27062  0.0  0.0   6908  3144 pts/25   T    23:50   0:00 sh ./sigstop.sh
ja       27063  0.0  0.0   2960  1664 pts/25   T    23:50   0:00 sleep 600
```

`ja` is my username, yours will be different, PIDs will also be
different but what matters is that both process are in stopped state
as indicated by letter 'T'. From `man ps`:

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
(...)
T    stopped by job control signal
```

That means that both processes got SIGTSTP signal. Now, if both
processes, including sigstop.sh get signal, why isn't
`suspense_cleanup()` signal handler run? Bash does not execute it
until `sleep 600` terminates. It's requirement imposed by
[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_14):

> When a signal for which a trap has been set is received while the
> shell is waiting for the completion of a utility executing a
> foreground command, the trap associated with that signal shall not be
> executed until after the foreground command has completed.

(notice though in the open-source world and IT in general standard is
just a collection of hints and there is no legal requirement to force
anyone to follow them). It wouldn't help if you slept less, say 3
seconds because `sleep` process would be stopped anyway so it would
never complete. In order for `suspense_cleanup()` to be called
immediately we have to run it in the background and run `wait` as also
explained in the above POSIX link:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

suspense_cleanup () {
  echo "Suspense clean up..."
}

int_cleanup () {
  echo "Int clean up..."
  exit 0
}

trap 'suspense_cleanup' SIGTSTP
trap 'int_cleanup' SIGINT

sleep 600 &
wait
```

Run it and stop it:

```
$ ./sigstop.sh
^ZSuspense clean up...
```

Notice that both `sleep 600` and `sigtstp.sh` are now gone:

```
$ ps aux | grep -e '[s]leep 600' -e '[s]igtstp.sh'
$
```

It's clear why sigtstp.sh is gone - `wait` was interrupted by signal,
it's the last line in the script so it exits. It's even more
surprising when you realize that if you sent SIGINT sleep would still
run even after death of sigtstp.sh:

```
$ ./sigtstp.sh
^CInt clean up...
$ ps aux | grep -e '[s]leep 600' -e '[s]igtstp.sh'
ja       32354  0.0  0.0   2960  1632 pts/25   S    00:12   0:00 sleep 600
```

But, due to its parent death it would be adopted by init:

```
$ grep PPid /proc/32354/status
PPid:   1
```

The reason for that is when shell runs a child in the background it
disables default SIGINT handler which is to terminate process
(signal(7)) in
it](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html):

> If job control is disabled (see the description of set -m) when the
> shell executes an asynchronous list, the commands in the list shall
> inherit from the shell a signal action of ignored (SIG_IGN) for the
> SIGINT and SIGQUIT signals. In all other cases, commands executed by
> the shell shall inherit the same signal actions as those inherited by
> the shell from its parent unless a signal action is modified by the
> trap special built-in (see trap)

Some SO references:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061694/bash-why-cant-i-set-a-trap-for-sigint-in-a-background-shell/46061734#46061734,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45106725/why-do-shells-ignore-sigint-and-sigquit-in-backgrounded-processes. If
you want to kill all children after receiving SIGINT you have to do it
manually in the trap handler. Notice, however, that SIGINT is still
delivered to all children but just ignored - if you didn't use sleep
but a command that installs its own SIGINT handler if would run (try
tcpdump for example)! [Glibc
manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html)
says:

> Note that if a given signal was previously set to be ignored, this
> code avoids altering that setting. This is because non-job-control
> shells often ignore certain signals when starting children, and it is
> important for the children to respect this.

But why is sleep dead after sending SIGTSTP to it if we don't kill it
ourselves and SIGTSTP should only stop it, not kill it? All stopped
process belonging to orphaned process group [get SIGHUP from
kernel](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html):

> If the exit of the process causes a process group to become orphaned,
> and if any member of the newly-orphaned process group is stopped, then
> a SIGHUP signal followed by a SIGCONT signal shall be sent to each
> process in the newly-orphaned process group.

SIGHUP terminates the process if no custom handler for it was
installed (signal(7)):

```
Signal      Standard   Action   Comment
SIGHUP       P1990      Term    Hangup detected on controlling terminal
                                or death of controlling process
```

(notice that if you ran sleep under strace things would get even more
complex...).

OK, so how about coming back to your original question:

> How can I:
>
> Run some cleanup code on Ctrl-Z, maybe even echoing something, and
> proceed with the suspension afterwards?

The way I would do it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

suspense_cleanup () {
    echo "Suspense clean up..."
    trap - SIGTSTP
    kill -TSTP $$
    trap 'suspense_cleanup' SIGTSTP
}

int_cleanup () {
    echo "Int clean up..."
    exit 0
}

trap 'suspense_cleanup' SIGTSTP
trap 'int_cleanup' SIGINT
sleep 600 &
while true
do
    if wait
    then
        echo child died, exiting
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Now `suspense_cleanup()` will be called before stopping the process:

```
$ ./sigtstp.sh
^ZSuspense clean up...

[1]+  Stopped                 ./sigtstp.sh
$ ps aux | grep -e '[s]leep 600' -e '[s]igtstp.sh'
ja        4129  0.0  0.0   6920  3196 pts/25   T    00:29   0:00 bash ./sigtstp.sh
ja        4130  0.0  0.0   2960  1660 pts/25   T    00:29   0:00 sleep 600
$ fg
./sigtstp.sh
^ZSuspense clean up...

[1]+  Stopped                 ./sigtstp.sh
$  fg
./sigtstp.sh
^CInt clean up...
$ ps aux | grep -e '[s]leep 600' -e '[s]igtstp.sh'
ja        4130  0.0  0.0   2960  1660 pts/25   S    00:29   0:00 sleep 600
$ grep PPid /proc/4130/status
PPid:   1
```

And you can sleep less, say 10 seconds and see that script would exit
if sleep finished:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

suspense_cleanup () {
    echo "Suspense clean up..."
    trap - SIGTSTP
    kill -TSTP $$
    trap 'suspense_cleanup' SIGTSTP
}

int_cleanup () {
    echo "Int clean up..."
    exit 0
}

trap 'suspense_cleanup' SIGTSTP
trap 'int_cleanup' SIGINT
# sleep 600 &
sleep 10 &
while true
do
    if wait
    then
        echo child died, exiting
        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Run it:

```
$ time ./sigtstp.sh
child died, exiting

real    0m10.007s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Answer (score -1):

It appears that Bash job control interferes with the normal tty special characters. SIGTSTP may be sent to Bash, but not to the process being run.

From https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control-Basics:

> If the operating system on which Bash is running supports job control,
> Bash contains facilities to use it. Typing the suspend character
> (typically ‘^Z’, Control-Z) while a process is running causes that
> process to be stopped and returns control to Bash.

Continue (Ctrl-Q, called `start` in `stty`) does not work under Bash job control: you need to `fg` or `bg` the process to un-stop it.

Comment: Not really, no. I can send TSTP and CONT to processes. See [Why did my trap not trigger?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282631/100397)

Comment: That's a slightly different issue: you can send signals from another terminal, and they will get deferred until the system sees fit to pass them to the process. My point is that Bash Ctrl-Z itself stops the process indefinitely: a stopped process cannot receive any signals. It cannot even be killed by SIGTERM until it is also restarted by Bash job control. It cannot be resumed by Ctrl-Q, but (special case) it can be resumed by SIGCONT.

Answer (score -2):

On reading `man 7 signal`, or  `https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html`, one sees that:

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored

So, you cannot.

Comment: But I'm using SIGTSTP

Comment: @SebastianCarlos  This says it should work. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html.